# Label points in listplot

Tags: plotting, labeling

The following command:

```
Show[Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 3}], ListPlot[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 4}, {3, 9}}]]
```

Yields the following figure:

[image]

I would like to add labels to each point. Each label would be a string containing the ordered pair for the point.

I know using the `Labeled[]` command in the following context

```
ListPlot[Table[Labeled[i, i], {i, 1, 5}]]
```

Yields this figure below:

[image]

I cannot find a way to combine the two commands to arrive at the desired result. This is mainly because I do not really understand how the `Labels[]` command works. Can anyone provide some guidance? Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the examples in the ListPlot documentation that use `Labeled`?  Have you checked the Details section of the same documentation page that describes the use of `Labeled`? Replace e.g. the `{1,1}` data point with `Labeled[{1,1}, "something"]` and see what happens.  I think this is really a case of "off topic because it is easily found in the documentation".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Example

This is one way how you could achieve the result.

```
Module[
 {
  offset = {0, .3},
  data = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 4}, {3, 9}}
  },
 Show[
  Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 3}],
  ListPlot[data],
  (* The line below adds Text above ea. data point *)
  Graphics @ Text["P" <> ToString @ #, # + offset] & /@ data
  ]
 ]
```

### Alternative

```
Module[
 {
  offset = {0, .3},
  data = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 4}, {3, 9}}
  },
 Show[
  Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 3}],
  ListPlot[data -> data, LabelingFunction -> (# &)]
  ]
 ]
```

### Reference

[Text](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Text.html)

Answer (score 1):

With V11

```
data = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 4}, {3, 9}};
dataForPlot = Map[Function[p, Callout[p, Style[p[[1]], Red, 14], Above]], data]
Show[ListPlot[dataForPlot], Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 3}], AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]